# SQL injection is possible but selected queries not working

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, sql-injection, java, mysql

I'm black-box testing an application which uses java spring framework and MySQL in the back-end.

When I insert a single quote (`'`) in a text box field, the server returns a HTTP status code 500 Internal server error with the below error stack trace,

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar
>   [select code, name, num_code from car where UPPER (code) LIKE UPPER('%'%') LIMIT 0,10];

So it's absolutely a SQL Injection.

And because of that, I tried to delete a row in another table which sits in the same DB with the below payload:

```
%'); DELETE FROM p_test WHERE t_id=1#
```

which will in-turn change the query as:

```
select code, name, num_code from car where UPPER (code) LIKE UPPER('%%'); DELETE FROM p_test WHERE t_id=1# %') LIMIT 0,10
```

Now a row must get deleted in the table *p_test* with `t_id = 1`, but it returns the HTTP status code 500 with below stack trace,

> [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR c.q.j.e.r.CommonHandlerExceptionResolver -  doResolveException going to resolve the following exception : 
>   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select code,name,num_code from car where UPPER (code) LIKE UPPER('%%'); DELETE FROM p_test WHERE t_id=2#%') LIMIT 0,10];
>   nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM p_test WHERE t_id=2#%') LIMIT 0,10' at line 1

If anyone has any idea please reply.

Comment: Why are you trying something so destructive like a `DELETE` and not something more interesting? Alternatively, try to incorporate remaining code in your statement with something like `%'); DELETE FROM p_test WHERE t_id=1 AND ('' LIKE '`.

Comment: Aren't comments in MySQL done by `--` instead of `#`?

Comment: @Qeole [MySQL has both comment styles.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comments.html)

Comment: @Gumbo Could you explain why you have added  AND ('' LIKE ' at the end of statement?

Comment: @williamcage To include the remaining code into the statement without using any comments. So the resulting `DELETE` would look like `DELETE FROM p_test WHERE t_id=1 AND ('' LIKE '%') LIMIT 0,10`, which is a completely valid statement and `('' LIKE '%')` is always true.

Comment: Are you sure you can execute multiple statements *at all*? As far as I can tell, JDBC uses batches for that, not standard queries.

Comment: @Gumbo I understood what you are trying to say. I tried the same and again get 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: @Fleche That was the doubt I had in my mind. Can I stack and execute multiple queries? Can you give me an example for batches?

Comment: @williamcage It may be possible that the database API won’t allow the execution of multiple statements.

Comment: @Gumbo I think your logic is wrong why are we applying LIMIT 0, 10 to delete command.

Comment: @Gumbo My query browser is executing the query DELETE FROM p_test WHERE t_id=1 AND ('' LIKE '%') but not with LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: @williamcage You’re right, the `LIMIT` in `DELETE` only allows a row count number but not an offset. In that case you could add another dummy `SELECT` after your `DELETE`.

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL client library doesn't allow multiple stacked queries by default, so you can't execute an arbitrary statement with this injection alone.

This is a handy mitigation against simple automated attacks, but with knowledge of the specific application there is still a lot you can do with a select injection. If you get to see the output of the query you can `UNION` with another select on a table you want to know about (otherwise see 'blind injection' for more tedious techniques to get that data out). If you have `SELECT INTO` permissions you can cause some real damage (arbitrary file write possibly escalating to executing arbitrary code).

Comment: +1, another good example of SQL Injection that isn't protected by eliminating stacking is modification of the `WHERE` clause.  This can often allow you to log in as any user or delete entire tables to name a few things.

Comment: [MySQL doesn’t support multiple statements by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html) but they can be enabled during connection with [`mysql_real_connect`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-real-connect.html).

Comment: @bobince I tried using UNION with another select.

Comment: @bobince But the tricky part is if I use comma somewhere in the query the whole grammar of actual query gets changed

Comment: @williamcage You can still use the boolean-based exploitation technique.

Comment: What is the issue with using a comma? You normally have to make sure you select the same number of columns of non-clashing data types, but other than that it should work. Are you saying there is some other processing of comma characters in the application layer?